# libxml2 error with namespaces and xpath

Tags: c, xml, xpath, namespaces, libxml2

I am pasting some code here that compiles with no warning using gcc file.c -lxml2, assuming that libxml2 is installed in your system.

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/xpathInternals.h>

xmlDocPtr
getdoc (char *docname) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

    if (doc == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return doc;
}

xmlXPathObjectPtr
getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath){

    xmlXPathContextPtr context;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;

    context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(xmlXPathRegisterNs(context,  BAD_CAST "new", BAD_CAST "http://www.example.com/new") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to register NS with prefix");
        return NULL;
    }

    result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(context);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
        xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
                printf("No result\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return result;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *docname;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "/new:book/section1";
    xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
    int i;
    xmlChar *keyword;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s docname\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }

    docname = argv[1];
    doc = getdoc(docname);
    result = getnodeset (doc, xpath);
    if (result) {
        nodeset = result->nodesetval;
        for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
            keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        printf("keyword: %s\n", keyword);
        xmlFree(keyword);
        }
        xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return (1);
}
```

My problem is that I want to parse the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns="http://www.example.com/new">
    <section1>Sec_1</section1>
    <section2>Sec_2</section2>
</book>
```

the book element defines a namespace inside that element. I want to print the value in the xpath /book/section1 and it returns NULL. When I am trying to return the element under a namespace I also get errors, ie /new:book/section1

I assume that my code fails because I am not using correctly the namespace prefixes. I run out of time. Could you please help?

Answer (score 33):

Turns out, as I found out from [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=530519),
it is not really a failure of libXml, it's a problem because libXml *correctly* follows the XML/XPATH specifications.

The solutions proposed by R Bourdeau are correct, however, if you have control of the xml document you are parsing.

The context for the XPATH query is *independent* of the namespace qualifiers in the xml document. The default namespace forces all child tags into a namespace; they don't require qualification *in the document* but **must** be qualified in the xpath query. Fortunately, you registered the namespace as `new` with libXml, so cateof's solution should work.

```
xmlXPathRegisterNs(context,  BAD_CAST "new", BAD_CAST "http://www.example.com/new"

xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "/new:book/new:section1";
```

I'm inlining the xml here for visibility:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns="http://www.example.com/new">
    <section1>Sec_1</section1>
    <section2>Sec_2</section2>
</book>
```

Comment: This is the first answer related to XPath and namespacing that actually explained what was going on and how to solve it. My sincere thanks to you my friend.

Answer (score 4):

This is an annoying failure of the libXml library. As noted by cateof, the problem is the default namespace declaration:

xmlns="http://www.example.com/new"

Two choices:
(1) get rid of that declaration in your book tag
or
(2) give it a name, and use that name in your tags.

e.g.

xmlns:new="http://www.example.com/new"

Then your tags all look like:

new:book
new:section1

and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to tell `libxml` that some namespace is default/implicit for all elements in a document to avoid repeating it over and over in XPath queries?

Answer (score 3):

it is an issue with the default namespace. To match a path you need /new:tag/new:tag
and so on